# /bin/sh: dumpsys: not found

Tags: adb, dumpsys

I am working on an 845 uSOM (Linux sda845 4.9.103) and want to modify USB charging/battery behavior. I'm not the most knowledgeable when it comes to working with adb, and I am not sure how to move forward. It seems that I can neither use 'dumpsys' or 'service call'. My ultimate goal is for things like:

```
adb shell dumpsys battery unplug
adb shell dumpsys battery set
```

I am told online that in order to find the name of the service I need in place of 'battery' I need to use:

```
adb shell service list
```

However, this isn't found either. Am I supposed to use systemctl at this point?

```
systemctl list-unit-files
```

yields a service called 'charger_monitor.service' but at this point I don't know if I've found something useful or I am completely off the scent. Do I need to get dumpsys on this system? I thought that if I could use adb on a device then dumpsys came along with it but maybe it is not applicable on this uSOM?